# The fractions are incomplete

Tags: python, fractions

I'm working with the  **fractions**  module of python.

I'm trying to get fractions that aproximates 2**.5. The problem is that when I use the Fraction command, it doesn't returns me what I want, because, for example, in i=2, the fractions that returns is 146666667/1000000000, but i want that it returns me 17/12 (The third aproximation of 2**.5). How i can solve it?

The code is this:

```
ai=2
bi=1
n=5
for i in range(n):
  ai=2+float(bi)/ai
  F=fr.Fraction(str(ai-1))
  print F
```

Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are going to work with fractions, don't do part of the calculation with floats. You can perform all the arithmetic with respect to fractions by making `ai` a Fraction:

```
import fractions
ai = fractions.Fraction(2)
bi = 1
n = 5
for i in range(n):
    ai = 2 + bi / ai
    F = ai - 1
    print(F)
```

yields

```
3/2
7/5
17/12
41/29
99/70
```

Answer (score 1):

Searching a little bit I found this function `limit_denominator(...)`, that could help you:

```
F = fr.Fraction(str(ai - 1)).limit_denominator(100)
```

**Output:**

```
3/2
7/5
17/12
41/29
99/70
```

Read more in [Fraction docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html).

Answer (score 1):

The fractions module is a great utility. Thanks for bringing it up here.

To control the denominator to more reasonable values, try adding limit_denominator() like this:

```
from fractions import Fraction
ai=2
bi=1
n=5
for i in range(n):
  ai=2+float(bi)/ai
  F=Fraction(str(ai-1)).limit_denominator(1000)
  print i, F
```

Output now looks like this:

```
%run "testFractions.py"
0 3/2
1 7/5
2 17/12
3 41/29
4 99/70
```